# TypeError: Schema is not a constructor when using mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular2-forms

```
var mysql  = require('mysql');
var Schema = mysql.Schema;

var HumanSchema = new Schema({
    fname  : String,
    lname  : String,
    age    : String,
    address: String,
    city   : String
})

var Model = mysql.Model('Human',HumanSchema);

module.exports = Model;
```

this is my Model code in Angular 2 and node js app.
When compiling it says

```
D:\Angular2MEANStack-master\models\model.js:3
var HumanSchema = new Schema({
                  ^

TypeError: Schema is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Angular2MEANStack-master\models\model.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Angular2MEANStack-master\routes\api.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

I have installed all the dependencies required. But cannot deploy this.

Comment: please edit your question so that the code is inside a code block. this will make it clearer.

Comment: Can't see anything like `mysql.schema` in the documentation (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql). Are you using the correct package?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you doing, you can't actually create a mysql database model that way with that npm package. You need to use an `ORM` connection tool like `sequelize` to be able to establish connection and perform operations in your mysql database. You might decide to go through this sequelize documentation to see how you can be able to do that.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

**mysql** is only a node.js driver for MySQL.

```
var mysql  = require('mysql');
```

In the above code you are using "mysql" driver and with that you can only use the specific functions that are provided by the library.

See documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql or https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

```
// Sample code with mysql
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'me',
    password: 'secret',
    database: 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Now, if you are looking for ORM to handle database interaction in well manner, you can use [**Sequelize**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started).